# Radius of convergence for a series with n!

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to find the radius of convergence for a series, and could use a hint.

The series is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

I've gotten as far as deciding that the radius will equal the reciprocal of $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]\frac{1}{n!}$, if it exists.  I can also see that the limit does, in fact, exist, since, $\forall n$, $\sqrt[n]\frac{1}{n!} \le \sqrt[n]\frac{1}{n}$, and the sequence $\{\sqrt[n]\frac{1}{n}\}$ converges to 1.  I don't know where I should start in trying to find the exact limit, however.

Comment: For any $r>0$, for every $n$ big enough we have $n!>r^n$, hence the radius of convergence is $+\infty$.

Comment: Use the Ratio Test, more pleasant in this case than Root Test.  As to finding the sum, if that is what you are looking for, it is very close to a familiar series.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That's interesting; how would you prove that, $\forall r\gt0$, $n! \gt r^n$ eventually?

Comment: @JohnFogg: an interesting chance is given by the identity $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}(n-k)^n = n!$$ that comes from the theory of forward differences. It shows that $n!$ behaves like $\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$, essentially, so $n>2re$ is more than enough to grant $n!>r^n$. That can be shown also through the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Another chance is given by noticing that $\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}=n+1$ while $\frac{r^{n+1}}{r^{n}}=r$, so $n!$ grows faster than $r^n$ for any $r\geq 2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: you are right, the Ratio Test is much nicer here.  I am happy to leave the sum alone for the moment, though.  Thank you for the hint.

Comment: what is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} z^n$ ? and generally of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  R^{-n} z^n$ ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: very cool, thank you.  I've never heard of the theory of forward differences, but the result follows easily enough from the idea that $n!$ is essentially $(\frac{n}{e})^n$.  The second way follows very naturally from ideas I'm already familiar with.

Comment: @user1952009: It would just be $R$, right?  By the Root Test?

Comment: yes but forget the root test, and prove it : $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$ for $|z| < 1$, hence $\sum_{n=0}^\infty R^{-n} z^n = \frac{1}{1-z/R}$ for $|z| < R$, hence any series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ with $|a_n| < C R^{-n}$ will have a radius of convergence $\ge R$ since $|\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n| < \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| |z|^n < C\sum_{n=0}^\infty R^{-n} |z|^n < \frac{C}{1-|z|/R}$ which cannot diverge when $|z| < R$

Comment: finally since $\frac{1}{n!}$ decreases faster than $R^{-n}$ for any $R$, the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ is $\ge R$ for any $R$, hence is $\infty$

Comment: @user1952009: ok, I think I follow that.  Is C any constant?  Also, it's cool that you try not to rely on rigid tests and go your own way.  How did you learn to math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of convergence is infinite; $z$ can be as big as it wants, and the series will still converge.

As proof: if we take $s_n$ to denote an individual term in the series, the Ratio Test tells us that the series converges as long as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}|<1$$

If we further note that

$$|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}|=|\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}|*|\frac{z^{n+1}}{z^n}|=\frac{1}{n+1}*z$$

then the convergence of $\frac{1}{n+1}$ to $0$ and the product property of limits imply that $|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}|$ converges to $0,$ and thus that the series converges, regardless of the value of $z$.

Thanks to [Andre Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andr%c3%a9-nicolas), who suggested this solution in the comments.  Thanks also to [Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44121/jack-daurizio) and [user1952009](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276986/user1952009), who suggested other solutions that, though less direct, are more interesting.